# Are my emails being hacked?

Tags: email

I receive a lot of emails from the Mailer Deamon. It says that it could not deliver a message I tried to send. But I did not try to send anything.

I have an email address that is forwarded to another email of mine.

```
my_gmx_address_that_gets_forwarded@gmx.de => my@email_adress.com
```

The message I get is:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> my@email_adress.com
>
> Reason:
>   multiple delivery attempts failed
>
> --- The header of the original message is following. ---
>
> Received: from avahost.ru ([212.146.244.254]) by mx-ha.gmx.net (mxgmx010
>    [212.227.15.9]) with ESMTP (Nemesis) id 0MUkzE-1hagMe3Fgi-00YDne for  my_gmx_address_that gets forwarded@gmx.de;
>   Sat, 09 Mar 2019 16:21:12 +0100
>   Received: by avahost.ru id hgfcvm16lt04 for my_gmx_address_that_gets_forwarded@gmx.de;
>   Sat, 9 Mar 2019 10:21:31 -0500 (envelope-from Kundenservice@avahost.ru)
>   X-Gm-Message-State: APjAAAUkA/Z1I9rvxQjR2IwB+xhH+t4WVmeDzO3RXwx8CJmixgVAbYkF KqnpLS/6uWAQZ4mLCg+EMNfXFVda
>   X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqxVUsl5ekebDKnZxNP6iX4SYD9/aUscnS4oYGSYIlnDjaOC6TMp4Z/yfsA6MXFYNUNK6VRtYcMDtLpXtkBHDolo
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   X-Received: by 2002:a0c:945c:: with SMTP id i28mr613047qvi.57.1551766778742; Mon, 04 Mar 2019 22:19:38 -0800 (PST)
>   X-Notifications: jk8qs8bxywg3fwhrxpb
>   Message-ID: X5thOme9BF4B-rcjxkajxvld.0@notifications.google.com
>   Subject: Gewichtsverlust von 10-12 Kg binnen eines Monats
>   From: Kundenservice noreply-maps-timeline@google.com.replayingdom.com
>   To: chaouisalman@gmail.com
>   Content-type:multipart/mixed; boundary="---- 
>    =_Part_121592_659013478.1551797199159"
>   Envelope-To: my_gmx_address_that_gets_forwarded@gmx.de
>   X-GMX-Antispam: 6 (nemesis text pattern profiler); Detail=V3; X-UI-Loop:V01:6afBCUOQJQ0=:u9DWyWBBaWAqM42eHRSUdgN4rZA148QSv0SckM/3wjM=

The message content is always different but one thing is always the same:

> To: chaouisalman@gmail.com

What is going on here?

Comment: That doesn't seem good. If you have never sent an email to that address but emails to it are getting bounced back, then it's possible that your password was compromised. Change your password immediately and configure 2FA (two-factor authentication).

Comment: See also [Receiving unknown bounced mails](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/155310/receiving-unknown-bounced-mails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one of your clients got its password stolen and tried to spam or send info toward that address. Password reset for that client usually solves this.

Technically, there are scripts that can interact with weak e-mail clients (like outlook) credential storage. They get the password and then can send a lot of messages to whoever they want (usually predefined lists) until external filters trigger and your whole server starts getting rejected e-mails due to low reputation or blacklisting. If the user clicked a one-time script, resetting the password of the account prevents further spam, but if the infiltration was more elaborate you will also have to do serious anti-virus and anti-malware checks on the affected system.